# Can anyone confirm if coffee-bytes works with eclipse oxygen?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-folding

The most recent version anyone has mentioned using **coffee-bytes** with is **Eclipse Neon**. Has anyone used this code-folding plugin on **Eclipse Oxygen**?

In my efforts:

- I installed coffee bytes from this link:  https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site
- the installation finished without any red-flags.
- under **Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Folding**, I have selected Coffee Bytes Java Folding.
- Under the **General** tab I have **User Defined Regions** Enabled
- Under the **User Defined Regions** tab, I created a user defined folding region with

  - **Start Identifier**: `{{`
  - **End Identifier**: `}}`
- I wrapped my code blocks as follows:

  - `// {{`
  - `MyCode();`
  - `// }}`

To my dismay, No folding buttons appear! Is it possible that my syntax is incorrect, or is this plugin functionality unavailable on this version?

- Edit : If anyone has any recommendations for plugins that enable user-defined regions that work with **Eclipse Oxygen**, I'll add you to my whitelist for when I take over the world. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the plugin with success! Installed the same way as described in the question.

- Eclipse 4.7.2
- Coffee Bytes 1.0.5.a

For your folding button problem try to change *Icon Theme Set* under *Advanced* tab.

Comment: Good tip, prior to changing the icon set I got small red square icons along the line numbers. I set my icon theme set in the Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Folding->Advanced Tab to 'Modern' and it fixed it.

Comment: This didn't do it for me. It is highlighting the line numbers that fall within the fold but nothing allows me to fold the code.